# Tkinter label writing over past text. Using lists so i cant use StringVar()

Tags: python, tkinter

So here is my problem.. I am making a messenger application using tkinter and sockets but for my GUI I am using the label widget to display incoming and outgoing messages. What I am trying to do is have a label retrieve an item from a list like the one in the code displayed and display it on screen. I tried using string variables but it cant call items from a list. Ive been at this for what seems like ages so if anyone knows the fix or a better way to do this please let me know.

```
# Easy settings
allow_incoming_connections = True # Allows anyone with your ip and port to connect to you. ('True' or 'False')
con_url = "google.com"
con_ip = ""
con_port = "80" 
#Add a IP blocker. sock.deny(idktheactuaulcode)

#Dont mess with the programming... it is barely held together xD
connected = False
from random import randrange
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk, socket, sys, tkinter.messagebox as tm, random
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x260")
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.iconbitmap(None)#make icon later after coding is done
window.title("Private Messenger")
window.cache = ['TkMessage','- Base 64 data encryption','- /host or /join a chat','- Saving supported','','','- /help for help','','','','Please select an alias:']
window.alias = StringVar()
if con_ip == "":
    con_ip = socket.gethostbyname(con_url)
class tkframe(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        window.bind("<Return>", self.send)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 4545))
        sock = socket.create_connection((con_ip, con_port),5)
#Variables      
        self.user_input = StringVar()
        self.updatewig()
    def updatewig(self):
        self.user_input.set("")
        input_box = Entry(self, textvariable = self.user_input, width=65).grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)
        input_button = ttk.Button(self, command = self.send, text="Send").grid(row=12, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[0]).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W) 
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[1]).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[2]).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[3]).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[4]).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[5]).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[6]).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[7]).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[8]).grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[9]).grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp = Label(self, text = window.cache[10]).grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.grid()
    def send(self):
        #self.textdisp.withdraw()
        try:
            self.char_check = str(self.user_input.get())[0]
        except:
            pass
        print(self.char_check)
        self.command = self.user_input.get()
        if self.char_check == "/":
            window.cache.append(self.user_input.get())
            del window.cache[0]
            self.user_input.set("")
            self.function()
        else:
            try:
                #send
                window.cache.append(("Me> "+self.user_input.get()))
                del window.cache[0]
            except:
                print("Message could not be sent")
            print(window.cache)
            self.updatewig()
    def function(self):
    # One long if statement to define all the commands 
        if self.command == "/host":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/join": 
            window.cache.append(("Enter IP:"))
            window.con_ip = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
            window.cache.append(("Enter Port:"))
            window.con_port = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
            window.cache.append(("Enter alias:"))
            window.alias = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/changealias":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/close":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/ban":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/encodeon":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/encodeoff":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/commands":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/mysettings":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/reset":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]

FRAME = tkframe(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually creating new `Label` widgets (in addition to `Entry` and `Button` widgets) over the existing ones anytime you call `self.updatewig` instead of just changing the text. You need to use the `config` method to change the text on the labels.

To do that, you first need to separate label creation from placement (`grid`) since grid returns `None` and you can't use `config` on `None` type. You also need to give the widgets distinct/separate names so you can call them later.

I moved the widget creation into the `__init__` method so that `updatewig` will only change the text of labels.

Here is the code, I hope it works the way you expected:

```
# Easy settings
allow_incoming_connections = True # Allows anyone with your ip and port to connect to you. ('True' or 'False')
con_url = "google.com"
con_ip = ""
con_port = "80" 
#Add a IP blocker. sock.deny(idktheactuaulcode)

#Dont mess with the programming... it is barely held together xD
connected = False
from random import randrange
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk, socket, sys, tkinter.messagebox as tm, random
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x260")
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.iconbitmap(None)#make icon later after coding is done
window.title("Private Messenger")
window.cache = ['TkMessage','- Base 64 data encryption','- /host or /join a chat','- Saving supported','','','- /help for help','','','','Please select an alias:']
window.alias = StringVar()
if con_ip == "":
    con_ip = socket.gethostbyname(con_url)
class tkframe(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        window.bind("<Return>", self.send)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 4545))
        sock = socket.create_connection((con_ip, con_port),5)

    #Variables      
        self.user_input = StringVar()

        ## Create widgets (input, button, labels) only once
        input_box = Entry(self, textvariable = self.user_input, width=65).grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)
        input_button = ttk.Button(self, command = self.send, text="Send").grid(row=12, column=2, sticky=W)

        ## Seperate label creation from grid (because grid will return 'None')
        ## Give labels different names
        self.textdisp00 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp01 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp02 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp03 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp04 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp05 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp06 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp07 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp08 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp09 = Label(self, text = "")
        self.textdisp10 = Label(self, text = "")

        ## Grid the labels
        self.textdisp00.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W) 
        self.textdisp01.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp02.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp03.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp04.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp05.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp06.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp07.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp08.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp09.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.textdisp10.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky=W)


        self.updatewig()

    def updatewig(self):
        ## Change content of the labels using 'config'
        self.user_input.set("")
        self.textdisp00.config(text = window.cache[0]) 
        self.textdisp01.config(text = window.cache[1]) 
        self.textdisp02.config(text = window.cache[2]) 
        self.textdisp03.config(text = window.cache[3]) 
        self.textdisp04.config(text = window.cache[4]) 
        self.textdisp05.config(text = window.cache[5]) 
        self.textdisp06.config(text = window.cache[6]) 
        self.textdisp07.config(text = window.cache[7]) 
        self.textdisp08.config(text = window.cache[8]) 
        self.textdisp09.config(text = window.cache[9]) 
        self.textdisp10.config(text = window.cache[10]) 
        self.grid()

    def send(self, *args): ## Pressing the return key throws an error, so added '*args' to make it work
        #self.textdisp.withdraw()
        try:
            self.char_check = str(self.user_input.get())[0]
        except:
            pass
        print(self.char_check)
        self.command = self.user_input.get()
        if self.char_check == "/":
            window.cache.append(self.user_input.get())
            del window.cache[0]
            self.user_input.set("")
            self.function()
        else:
            try:
                #send
                window.cache.append(("Me> "+self.user_input.get()))
                del window.cache[0]
            except:
                print("Message could not be sent")
            print(window.cache)
            self.updatewig()
    def function(self):
    # One long if statement to define all the commands 
        if self.command == "/host":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/join": 
            window.cache.append(("Enter IP:"))
            window.con_ip = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
            window.cache.append(("Enter Port:"))
            window.con_port = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
            window.cache.append(("Enter alias:"))
            window.alias = self.user_input.get()
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/changealias":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/close":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/ban":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/encodeon":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/encodeoff":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/commands":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/mysettings":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]
        elif self.command == "/reset":
            window.cache.append(("This command is not yet available."))
            del window.cache[0]

FRAME = tkframe(window)
window.mainloop()
```

**Note**

1. The `send` method was throwing an error about extra argument when the `Return` key is pressed so I added `*args` as a parameter. Now it should work for both the `Return` key and the 'Send' button.
2. It will probably be easier (and better?) to use a single `Text` widget with `Normal` and `Disable` states in place of the `Label`s. I did not use it in my answer because I don't know the reason for which you're using labels.

Comment: I was using labels simply just to display text in a list like fashion. The most recent messages would be on the bottom and then rest would be bumped up one row. If you know of a better way to display text i would much appreciate it